# Calling a function from a .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, function

i'm trying to call function select () which is inside of the variable Select, but function select() claims it isn't being called upon? How do I get function select () to realize its being called.

```
<p id="button"></p>

<p id="list"></p>

<script>
function buttons() {
var Select = "<button type='button' onclick='select()'>Sort</button>";
document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = Select;
}

function select() {document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = fruits;}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no element with `id` == "buttons".  Did you mean "button"?

Comment: change your id = "buttons"  and call the function buttons()

Comment: What console messages do you see?

Answer (score 3):

- You haven't called `buttons()` anywhere so your button which has it's click event bound to `select()` is never created.
- Also you have a typo in the buttons id. It says button.
- Finally `'fruits'` has to be in quotes, otherwise JS thinks you are trying to reference a variable called `fruits` and throws a reference error.

```html
<p id="buttons"></p>

<p id="list"></p>

<script>
function buttons() {
  var Select = "<button type='button' onclick='select()'>Sort</button>";
  document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = Select;
}

function select() {
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = 'fruits';
}
  
buttons()
</script>
```